# AngularJS binding data and click

Tags: angularjs-directive

I am trying to update the content in a second directive from a click in the first. Is this a scoping problem of some type? I have mainly taken code from the bootstrap carousel. https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/master/src/carousel

I have tickets and a ticket icon. I want the corresponding ticket displayed when an icon is clicked on. Model currently has {name: 'name', type: 'home'}.

Two directives ticketicons and tickets are called:

```
 <body>
    <div ng-controller="TicketSwipeCtrl">
        <!-- for itinerary in itineraries -->
        <ticketicons></ticketicons>
        <ticket></ticket>
```

Plnkr code at [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ca5QB6?p=preview)

The expected result is that the name - AQVVMF.htm is changed to NWMMRE.htm when the second bullet is clicked on. The javascript console does print out the event.

A complete sample code is :

```
var clickTest = angular.module('clickTest', ['interlated.ticketSwipeTest', 'template/travelbytes/iconbar.html']);

function TestClickCtrl($scope) {
}

angular.module("template/travelbytes/iconbar.html", []).run(["$templateCache",    function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("template/travelbytes/iconbar.html",
            "<div ng-mouseenter=\"pause()\" ng-mouseleave=\"play()\" class=\"carousel\">\n" +
            "<h2>Icon Row {{tickets().length}}</h2>\n" +
            "    <ul class=\"nav-swipe pull-left text-center\" ng-show=\"tickets().length > 1\">\n" +
            "        <li ng-repeat=\"ticket in tickets()\" <i ng-click=\"select(ticket)\" class=\"icon-{{ticket.type}}\"></i></li>\n" +
            "    </ol>\n" +
            "</div>\n" +
            "");
}]);

var ticketSlideModule = angular.module('interlated.ticketSwipeTest', ['ui.bootstrap.transition', "template/travelbytes/iconbar.html"])
    .controller('TicketSwipeTest', ['$scope', '$timeout', '$transition', '$q', '$log', '$http',
function($scope, $timeout, $transition, $q, $log, $http) {
    var self = this;
    self.log = $log;
    var tickets =
            [{name: 'AQVVMF.htm', type: 'road'}, {name: 'NWMMRE.htm', type: 'home'}];

    var currentTicket = $scope.$currentTicket = tickets[0];

    self.select = function(ticket, direction) {
        var nextIndex = tickets.indexOf(ticket);
        currentTicket = ticket;
    };

    $scope.currentTicket = function() {
        $log.log('currentTicket: %s', currentTicket.name);
        return currentTicket;
    }

    $scope.tickets = function() {
        return tickets;
    }
}]);

ticketSlideModule.directive('ticketicons', [function() {
    var directiveDefinitionObject = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        controller: 'TicketSwipeTest',
        require: 'ticketSwipeTest',
        templateUrl: 'template/travelbytes/iconbar.html',
    };

    return directiveDefinitionObject;
}])


ticketSlideModule.directive('ticket', ['$parse', function($parse) {
    return {
        require: 'interlated.ticketCarousel',
        controller: 'TicketSwipeTest',
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: '<div>{{currentTicket().name}} test</div>',
        scope: {
        }};
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove the scope property of your ticket directive. This is creating an isolated scope that does not inherit the functions and properties of the parent, which is what you want.

You also need to change self.select to $scope.select and add some text to your icon element so that it is clickable.

As an aside, you don't have to create property accessors for your model objects. You can take that tickets function and just replace it with `$scope.tickets = tickets;`. I've never seen an angular example where they recommend the use of function accessors, and I am pretty sure that their dirty checking algorithm won't be able to handle functions as well as plain old javascript objects (POJOs).

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/drR1df?p=preview)

First change:

```
ticketSlideModule.directive('ticket', ['$parse',
    function ($parse) {
        return {
            require: 'interlated.ticketCarousel',
            controller: 'TicketSwipeTest',
            restrict: 'EA',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            template: '<div>{{currentTicket().name}} test</div>'
            // [CHANGE] Removed scope to stop using an isolated scope
        };
    }
]);
```

Second change:

```
var currentTicket = $scope.$currentTicket = tickets[0];
// [CHANGE] change self to $scope.
$scope.select = function (ticket, direction) {
    var nextIndex = tickets.indexOf(ticket);
    currentTicket = ticket;
};
```